# jQuery get closest option by option text

Tags: jquery, selected, closest

I need to get the option by the name or value of it and insert selected to it.

For example, I have this:

```
<select class="numbers_class">
<option value="">Select the Number</option>
<option value="1">Number 1</option>
<option value="2">Number 2</option>
<option value="3">Number 3</option>
<option value="4">Number 4</option>
<option value="5">Number 5</option>
</select>
```

And I need the jquery to find the "numbers_class" and let's say option with number 3 of it. And then set 'selected' attribute to it.

Comment: How about showing us the jQuery code you have created?

Comment: `$('.numbers_class option[value="3"]').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/taltmann/48en8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get by name:

```
var option = $(".numbers_class option:contains('Number 3')");
```

Or get by value:

```
var option = $(".numbers_class option[value='3']");
```

Set selected attribute:

```
option.prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: Good list. I'd mention that `:contains` is a substring search so watch out for "Number 30" through "Number 39" getting selected by accident. And add one more: a shortcut for finding an option by value and setting selected property: `$(".numbers_class).val(3)